# Warum wird hier kein Genitiv verwendet: "... einschließlich Marke, Urheberrecht, Produkt, Firma und Informationsversion"?

Tags: preposition

Gemäß dieser [Seite](http://www.lsa.umich.edu/german/hmr/Grammatik/Praepositionen/Prepositions2.html#ausschliesslich) ist "einschließlich" eine Genitivpräposition.

Jedoch finde ich hier das Wort "einschließlich" ohne Genitiv verwendet:

> Im Assemblymanifest können Sie Informationen hinzufügen oder ändern.
>   Dazu müssen Sie Assemblyattribute im Code verwenden. Sie können
>   Versionsinformationen und Informationsattribute ändern, ***einschließlich***
>   Marke, Urheberrecht, Produkt, Firma und Informationsversion.

(Hier ist der [Kontext](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/app-domains/assembly-manifest))

Englisch:

> You can change version information and informational attributes,
>   including Trademark, Copyright, Product, Company, and Informational
>   Version.

Wie ist das Fehlen der Genitivform an den Substantiven zu erklären?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Einschließlich* ist eine Präposition, die einen sehr wandelbaren Charakter hat, je nachdem, vor welchen Wortgruppen sie steht:

1. Wie du richtig sagst, steht *einschließlich* normalerweise mit dem Genitiv, vor allem vor vollständigen Satzteilen, die aus Artikel und Substantiv bestehen (das ist die Standardanwendung, der "klassisch richtige" Fall bei *einschließlich*):

   > Der Preis beträgt 10,99€, einschließlich des Portos ins Ausland und der für einen sicheren Transport notwendigen Verpackung.
2. Steht *einschließlich* vor einem Substantiv im Plural, bei dem der Genitiv nicht erkennbar wäre, darf der Dativ stehen (nicht dein Fall, klassisch nicht unbedingt richtig, aber akzeptiert und vom Duden abgesegnet)

   > Der Preis, einschließlich Getränken, beträgt 10€ pro Teilnehmer.
3. Steht *einschließlich* vor einem allein stehenden Substantiv, das weder (gebeugten) Artikel noch (gebeugtes) Adjektiv dabei hat, wird *in der Regel* das Substantiv nicht gebeugt (Das ist dein Fall, allerdings hast du kein allein stehendes Substantiv, sondern eine Liste allein stehender Substantive). Der Duden führt diese Form explizit als erlaubt an, ich gehe aber davon aus, dass es sich hier um "Dokumentation einer eigentlich falschen Anwendung, die nur traditionell sehr verbreitet ist" handelt:

   > Der Preis einschließlich Auf- und Abladen beträgt 10€

Dein Fall ist der Fall 3, bei dem sich *einschließlich* nur auf **allein stehende** Substantive bezieht. Würde dort in deinem Beispiel statt "Informationsversion"  z.B. "die derzeit aktuelle Version der Information" stehen, wäre Fall 3 nicht mehr anwendbar und das Substantiv müsste im Genitiv stehen.

Answer (score 1):

Hier sind "Marke", "Urheberrecht" etc Namen von Informationsattributen.

Man könnte sich daher vorstellen, sie würden unter Anführungszeichen stehen und deshalb nicht gebeugt werden:

> ...**einschließlich** "Marke", "Urheberrecht", "Produkt", "Firma" und "Informationsversion"

Die gebeugte Version "einschließlich [...] des Urheberrechts [...]" würde den Fokus darauf legen, dass man das Urheberrecht (gemeint ist wohl die Lizenz) festlegt, während die obige Variante den Fokus darauf legt, dass man die Information über das Urheberrecht festlegt.

Comment: Da gehören sicher keine Anführungszeichen hin, auch wenn das manche glauben.

Comment: Es gehören definitiv keine expliziten Anführungszeichen hin. Das ändert nichts daran, dass die Wörter "Eigennamen" von Attributen sind, so als würden sie unter Anführungszeichen stehen.

Comment: "Eigennamen von Attributen" ist Quatsch - steht das Wort Eigennamen deswegen in Anführungsstrichen? Nil ist ein Eigenname. Es gibt einen Fluss der so heißt. Beatles ist ein Eigenname, Beatmusik nicht. Marke, Urheberrecht usw. sind Bezeichnungen für Kategorien und gerade keine Eigennamen. Deiner Erklärung nach ist jedes Wort ein Eigenname was den Begriff seiner Signifikanz beraubt.